# Setting checkbox checked on page load in the Metronic AngularJS theme

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, metronic

I am developing an AngularJS app using the Metronic Admin Dashboard template. This is the code for my checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="checkbox.isEnabled"> Enabled?
    </label>
</div>
```

I've confirmed that the value of `checkbox.isEnabled` is in fact `true`. I've also tried using `data-ng-checked="checkbox.isEnabled`, this also did not work. If I call `Metronic.updateUniform();` after the page has fully loaded (I attached it to the click event of an  tag) the checkbox DOES correctly update.

I can't seem to find a place where I can make the call. `updateUniform()` ui-router's `$stateChangeSuccess` event is still too early. Is there something I'm missing or is it really not possible to pre-check one of Metronic's themed checkboxes based on data in AnguularJS?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this line after the prop

```
$.uniform.update();
```